# Charles - How to filter the recording using the "client address" field?

Tags: proxy, remote-debugging, charles-proxy

I am debugging on my computer by means of adding its IP as the proxy in my iPad. I just need to see the traffic coming from iPad and not the computer.

The IP of the iPad is mentioned in the "client address" field of the Overview section. How do I see the requests coming from only that IP?

Comment: "client address" field where, in charles or the ipad?

Comment: Is it just other traffic you're picking up in charles, or is the ipad traffic not showing? I presume you just want to solely capture the ipad, but are picking up your computer traffic as well.

Comment: ^ Spot on. How do I only see the traffic from the iPad?

Comment: Selected answer isn’t correct as it just enables you to you see the traffic coming in from your iPad. It does not filter so that you only see the traffic coming from it as per your question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Command+Shift+P should do the trick, or toggle off `MAC OS X Proxy` from the `Proxy` menu.

[image]

Comment: Figured this out myself just now. This should be the correct answer.

Comment: @Simon: Enabling this option allows traffic to pass through Charles, **it does not exclude incoming/outgoing traffic on the host machine used as the proxy** — which is what the OP asks about.

Comment: The OP was speaking about what they can *see*. There was no mention of literally excluding the host machine's network calls.

Comment: "I just need to see the traffic coming from iPad and not the computer. "

Comment: This is the correct answer!  Everything else is just flat out wrong and does not stop local traffic from being displayed.

Answer (score 37):

**Under Proxy > Recording Settings**

You can enter specific locations to exclusively record requests to/from using `include`, or `exclude` to prevent locations from recording. It's also possible to blacklist requests as needed by control-clicking in the `structure` section and selecting ignore. If you want to exclude requests to/from the computer that Charles is running on then you'll need to close it's web browser, email, etc. to keep internet requests intended to/from it to a minimum. **You cannot ignore the host machine Charles is running on since it's used as the proxy** — but you can selectively include/exclude other machines/clients by using [access control](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/access-control/).

[image: charles proxy settings]

**To use Charles as a "*Man in the middle*"**:

Keyboard shortcut <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd>, or choose from the menu use `Proxy` > `Mac OS X Proxy`.

> **NOTE**: Option does not exclude (host) traffic incoming/outgoing  on machine used as proxy.

Comment: I can't believe this isn't a dead-simple feature to enable.  This seems like an extremely common request, i.e. "Hey, only show traffic from this IP address" and yet, if it's even possible, it involves extremely convoluted steps.

Comment: The problem here is that IT IS so dead simple that people don't understand it.  In the Filter area just enter the client IP address you want to filter for.
https://freeimage.host/i/jleRLl

Answer (score 6):

You can also disable the proxy for your machine. This way, the only connected client will be the ipad. 
On your Mac OS X, just go to **System Preferences** > **Network** > Select active network device > **Advanced** > **Proxies** and uncheck both **Web Proxy** and **Secure Web Proxy**

Comment: This is great except it kills the internet connection on the computer.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the Filter feature for it.

[image]